# Is it possible to get the the layer returned by a GRASS tool without saving it to disk in QGIS?

Tags: qgis, pyqgis, grass-gis, qgis-processing

I use some GRASS tools in QGIS Python Console. All tools I use return a dictionary with a key and a value which contains string path, like this: `{"output": "file/path"}`. There is an [answer here](https://gis.stackexchange.com/a/368702/156679). It suggests to use that string in `QgsVectorLayer`. But writing/reading a file to/from disk is time consuming.

I tried `processing.runAndLoadResults` and `processing.run`. Both add a layer. But before adding the layer, they save the layer to disk, then add it.

```
processing.run("grass7:v.buffer", {..., 'output':'TEMPORARY_OUTPUT', ...})
# returns {'output': '/tmp/.../output.gpkg'} -> file path

processing.runAndLoadResults("grass7:v.buffer", , {..., 'output':'TEMPORARY_OUTPUT', ...})
# returns {'output': '/tmp/.../output.gpkg'} -> file path
```

I wonder, is there a way to get the returned/added layer by the GRASS tool without saving to disk (to use in the next processing tool in a Python script)?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't think there is a way when using a GRASS tool in QGIS. I noted that GRASS tools I used always returned file path. The only way I could achieve to get layer without saving it was to use QGIS native processing tools via `processing.run` method. [This answer](https://gis.stackexchange.com/a/280468/29431) explains how to do.

If you use the output layer as intermediate layer, I recommend you to use equivalent native(QGIS) tool (if exists) via `processing.run` which returns `QgsVectorLayer` instance without saving it to disk. Otherwise, I suggest you to run a tool using `processing.run` and then use `QgsVectorLayer` to add the output to memory.